# AWS API Gateway -- Add Header to Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

AWS question. I have a Lambda sitting behind an API Gateway and want to add an additional header element on every response back to the client.   I couldn't find clear documentaion on how to do that.

Read and researched AWS documentation.

Comment: Is this what you need - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html#mapping-response-parameters

Answer (score 0):

Please add more information about type of ApiGw and lambda lang. But for Rest ApiGW in Method Response section for your method
[image]
In case of lambda implementation, you have headers field. You did not mention about your lambda's language, but something like this:

```
exports.handler = async function (event) {
  var response = {
    statusCode: 200,
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-My-Header': 'super'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({status: 'OK'}),
  }
  
  return response
}
```

steps to add static header
[image]
[image]
and test
[image]

Comment: Hi.  Yes,  a Javascript Lambda.  I was hoping to be able to configure the API Gateway independent of any code changes.   I can do it all in the code but have many API Gateway/Lambda implementations to do it for and trying to avoid code changes if possible.   Your screenshot above is where I thought it could be done.   But haven't been successful configuring it.

Comment: hmm, strange. May be your receiver do not support additional headers. Anyway please have a look at this https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/overriding-request-response-parameters-and-response-status-in-amazon-api-gateway/
and this
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/request-response-data-mappings.html

Comment: Sorry, what I was trying to say was I could not figure out how to configure the Method Response (your screenshot above) to actually add the header.

Comment: Ok, to add header you can try 1. add a variable, a header name in Method response 2. go to Integration Response and add value there in Header Mapping. I updated screenshots in answer.

Comment: So to use this strategy then I need to configure the gateway to NOT use the Lambda Proxy correct?   Meaning, I'll have access to the Integration Response configuration?

Comment: So I have it working via the API Gateway Test panel, but if I make a real call to the service via Postman the new custom header is not returned.

Comment: In this example headers were added just for one method and only for 200 results. I can only assume that your lambda respond was not with 200 result code or another method was triggered by postman. It is very hard to find out reason remotely.

Comment: Yea, checked both items of those multiple times.  The service I'm testing with only has one API.   So it can't route anywhere else except to it.  And it's returning a 200.